Cordova - Stripe - Apple Pay?
I have a cordova app. I'm looking to implement ApplePay option to the stripe form. Is this possible using stripe checkout within a cordova app for Apple pay? or is it Safari only?
I have cordova-plugin-applepay installed along with the following script:
   require_once('/var/www/vhosts/stripe-php-latest/init.php');

    // Initialize Stripe
        const stripe = Stripe('<?php echo $key; ?>');

        // Create a payment request
        const paymentRequest = stripe.paymentRequest({
            country: 'US',
            currency: 'usd',
            total: {
                label: 'Demo total',
                amount: 100,
            },
            requestPayerName: true,
            requestPayerEmail: true,
        });

        // Check the availability of the Payment Request API
        const elements = stripe.elements();
        const prButton = elements.create('paymentRequestButton', {
            paymentRequest: paymentRequest,
        });

        // Check if the Apple Pay button can be displayed
        paymentRequest.canMakePayment().then(function (result) {
            if (result) {
                document.getElementById('apple-pay-button').style.display = 'block';
                prButton.mount('#apple-pay-button');
                alert('Apple Pay');
            } else {
                alert('Apple Pay is not available.');
            }
        });

        // Handle payment method creation
        paymentRequest.on('paymentmethod', async (ev) => {
            const {paymentIntent, error: backendError} = await fetch('<?php echo $root;?>nav/pay/payment.php', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    payment_method: ev.paymentMethod.id,
                }),
            }).then(r => r.json());

            if (backendError) {
                ev.complete('fail');
                console.error(backendError);
            } else {
                ev.complete('success');
                stripe.confirmCardPayment(paymentIntent.client_secret).then(function (result) {
                    if (result.error) {
                        console.error(result.error.message);
                    } else if (result.paymentIntent.status === 'succeeded') {
                        console.log('Payment succeeded!');
                    }
                });
            }
        });

but its returning "Apple Pay is not available." either i'm implenting the code completely wrong or its just not supported?
I'm stuck with cordova for now and unable to change to ionic / capacitor.
Has anyone had success with stripe.js / cordova / apple pay?

If you are using the PaymentRequestButton, Apple Pay will be displayed only if you follow all requirements listed here.
But note that Apple Pay doesn't always work inside of webviews, and Google Pay never works in webviews. So the PaymentRequestButton might not function well with Cordova.
For mobile apps, the recommendation is to use Mobile Elements or simply to redirect users to a website using a real browser (not a webview).

thank you. looked at the documents from your links. Is there away stripe can display apple pay only as an option using elements / express checkout? or does it have to go to external webpage?

The PaymentRequestButton and Express Checkout Element can display Apple/Google Pay. But if you are using webviews it might not work, that's why I recommended redirecting users to a real browser or using the Mobile Elements.
